# Cannot store oauth token in session (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth

K guys, so I was workign with the dialybooth api, and OAauth, so first, I had straight up

```
 #first redirect the user to the authorize_url
  redirect_to dailybooth.authorize_url

 #on user return grab the code from the query string
 dailybooth.oauth_token(params[:code])

 #make request to the api
 pp dailybooth.get('/users.json')
```

Problem was, it would constant redirect, because it wasn't even checking if the oauth_token was set, so then I did this;

```
unless dailybooth.oauth_token(params[:code])
 #first redirect the user to the authorize_url
 redirect_to dailybooth.authorize_url

 #on user return grab the code from the query string
 dailybooth.oauth_token(params[:code])
end


#make request to the api
pp dailybooth.get('/users.json')
```

Now, this send me to the dailybooth authorization page, the user authorized, then was sent to my page, and I gained access to their account (an array with the user info was returned), thing is if you refreshed the token did not exist anymore, and the user had to re-authorize.

So what I tried was to store the oauth_token in a session,

```
if session[:oauth_code]  #If session is set
  dailybooth.oauth_token(session[:oauth_code]) #sign in using cookie
else
  if params[:code]
    @oauth_token_ = params[:code]
    session[:oauth_code] = @oauth_token_
  else
      #first redirect the user to the authorize_url
      redirect_to dailybooth.authorize_url
  end
end



#make request to the api
@info = dailybooth.get('/users.json')

if @info['error']      
  if @info['error']['error_code'] 
    if @info['error']['error_code'] == 302 #if getting invalid token, request another token.
      session[:oauth_code] = nil
      #first redirect the user to the authorize_url
      redirect_to dailybooth.authorize_url

    end
  end
end
```

I'm still getting the same thing, when I first go to my website, and I'm redirected to the authorization page, it authorities, then I get access to the account, but when I try to go back to the index, it says the oauth_token is invalid. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest, I'm not 100% sure (and DailyBooth's API documentation is...lacking, to say the least), but I believe that you use the "token" (the one you're getting from `params[:code]` and storing in `@oauth_token_`) to get an access token, and then store the access token (e.g. store the result form `dailybooth.oauth_token(session[:oauth_code])` instead, or at least a portion of it, if it's an object/array).

```
unless session[:oauth_code] #unless the session is set
  if params[:code]
    session[:oauth_code] = dailybooth.oauth_token(params[:code])
  else
    #first redirect the user to the authorize_url
    redirect_to dailybooth.authorize_url
  end
end

#make request to the api
@info = dailybooth.get('/users.json')

if @info['error']      
  if @info['error']['error_code'] 
    if @info['error']['error_code'] == 302 #if getting invalid token, request another token.
      session[:oauth_code] = nil
      #first redirect the user to the authorize_url
      redirect_to dailybooth.authorize_url

    end
  end
end
```

I hope this points you in the right direction.